# How do I define an any-to-any mapping in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to define a completely generic mapping in c++ where I can map anything to anything.

I tried std::map but what should K and V be to make it general enough so I can map primitives or objects (as keys) to other primitives or objects (as values).

Or is there another mechanism I could use?

EDIT: For clarification, I am trying to define a relationship in the base class (from which all my classes are derived) that will allow me to attach arbitrary data to my classes. The simplest approach would be a be a name-value pair, where the above key is a string. I was wondering if i do something more generic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Impossible- as it should be. Such a mapping would be worthless, since you can't depend on any meaningful behaviour of either key or value, and it's impossible to design either a binary relation or hash function that would be meaningful across "anything", or that could operate on any type, so it's nowhere near even the realm of possible.

Edit: There is nothing preventing `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>`- or indeed, `boost::any` which happens to hold a `std::unordered_map` of some types.

However, your design appears highly questionable. You're basically completely subverting the compiler for no apparent benefit. Why would you derive every class from a common base? And why on earth would you want to attach arbitrary data? The usual way to put data in a class is to *put it in the class*, not blow all your safety and performance and sanity by trying to coerce C++ into being an interpreted language.

Comment: By the way, good solution with the `std::unordered_map`. More reason for my earlier +1!

Comment: Good points @DeadMG. I derive from a common class because this is limited functionality (so not many derived classes), but I don't know in advance what clients of these classes need to attach as supplementary data.

Comment: @AndrewS.: Make the clients worry about associating data to them- if they even need that functionality. They can do `std::unordered_map<Derived*, ThatDataWhichINeed>` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - so in this point I disagree with @DeadMG.

It is worthless - in this point full agreement,

However I do not understand that concept of answering, I mean "don't do it" answers instead "it can be done in this way, but my advise is don't do it". I do not pretend to be "life teacher" - I am just answering,

For values - use something like boost::any.

For keys - it is more complicated - because std::map defines order in keys. So generic keys must follow thess rules:

1. If real keys types are the same - use order from the real keys
2. If real keys are not the same - you must define order between types (like order of typeinfo::name())
3. Generic keys must be copy constructible

Let see my proposal for keys (using type erasure):

```
template <typename T>
struct GenKeyTypeOrder;


class GenKeyImplInt {
public:
   // true if before other Key in other 
   virtual bool before(const GenKeyImplInt&) const = 0;
   // type value
   virtual int typeOrder() const = 0;

   virtual GenKeyImplInt* clone() const = 0;
   virtual ~GenKeyImplInt() {}
};

template <typename RealKey>
class GenKeyImpl : public GenKeyImplInt {
public:
   GenKeyImpl(RealKey realKey) : realKey(realKey) {}
   // true if before other Key in other 
   virtual bool before(const GenKeyImplInt& r) const 
   { 
      const GenKeyImpl* rp = dynamic_cast<const GenKeyImpl*>(&r);
      if (rp) return realKey < rp->realKey;
      return typeOrder() < r.typeOrder();
   }
   // type value
   virtual int typeOrder() const { return GenKeyTypeOrder<RealKey>::VALUE; }

   virtual GenKeyImpl* clone() const { return new GenKeyImpl(*this); }
private:
   RealKey realKey;
};

class GenKey {
public:
   // true if before other Key in other 
   friend bool operator < (const GenKey& l, const GenKey& r) 
   {
       return l.impl->before(*r.impl);
   }
   template <typename T>
   GenKey(T t) : impl(new GenKeyImpl<T>(t)) {}
   GenKey(const GenKey& oth) : impl(oth.impl->clone()) {}
   ~GenKey() { delete impl; }
private:
   GenKey& operator = (const GenKey& oth); // not defined
   GenKeyImplInt* impl;
};


// define for every type you want be used as generic key
template <>
struct GenKeyTypeOrder<int> { enum { VALUE = 0 }; };
template <>
struct GenKeyTypeOrder<std::string> { enum { VALUE = 1 }; };
```

Full example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/gCaEZ) 
See also this [article](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/ValuedConversions.pdf)

Comment: You haven't mapped anything to anything. You have only mapped types which have been specifically registered as such *and* support `operator<`.

Comment: @DeadMG This was just a first try to solve the problem. I can easily imagine generic type order - so that type do not need to be specifically registered. E.g. using typeid(T).name(). For the second issue: one can define for some types specific order, leaving std::less<> as default. Quite another solution would be unordered/hash map - with hash function taking into account, for example, type name (typeid) and string representation of object, and as final selector `operator ==`. BTW, do you know class of objects where `operator <` cannot be defined?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make K and V be special objects.

The object will need to include what object type it is.

```
struct {
  void *pointer;
  string type;
  // int type; // this is also possible
} Object;
```

The above Object can point to anything. However, it also needs something to say what type it is, hence the type string.

Then you need to be able to cast the pointer back to the required type, by reading what is in type.

Eg.

```
if (type == "int") cout << (int*)(myobject.pointer) << endl;
```

Anyways, if you do something like this, you are almost starting to build a loosely-typed interpreter, because for any operation you want to do with the object, you will need to check its type (whether you are adding, concatenating or printing the value to stdout).

---

It is probably better if you use a class object, and use inheritance to store any data you need.

```
class Object {
  public virtual string to_string() {
    return "";
  }
};
```

Then if you want to store an integer:

```
class Integer : public Object {
  int i;
  public string to_string() {
    char str[50];
    sprintf(str,"%d",i);
    return string(str);
  }
  public Integer operator=(int a) {
    i=a;
    return this;
  }
};
```

This way you can define an interface of all the functions you want all objects to support.

Note that making the base Object class have virtual functions means that if you say:

```
Integer a;
a=5;
Object object = (Object)a;
cout << object.to_string << endl; // prints "5"
```

So that the function called is that defined by the actual (true) type of the object.